# How to solve mckp (multiple-choice knapsack problem) problem with non-linear constraint

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, variational-inequalities

How to solve the below optimization problem? $P$ is a probability matrix, $0\le P_{ij}\le 1$. Are there any developed tools to solve this? Thanks a lot.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&\underset{X}{\operatorname{argmax}} && \sum_{i}\sum_{j} X_{ij} \times P_{ij} \times  w_j \\
&\text{subject to} && \sum_{j} X_{ij} = 1 \quad i=1,\ldots,N \quad AND  \quad  \forall{i,j} \quad X_{ij} \in (0,1) \\
& && \frac{\sum_{i}\sum_{j} X_{ij} \times P_{ij} \times  w_j }{\sum_{i}\sum_{j} X_{ij} \times P_{ij} } \hspace{5mm} \ge ARPU_{threshold} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: If $P_{ij}$ and $w_j$ are input parameters, you can linearize by clearing the denominator.

Comment: Yes, they are both constant parameters. But the denominator has $X_{ij}$ inside, how can I clear it? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The LHS is a ratio of linear functions.  Multiplying both sides of the constraint by the denominator yields a linear constraint.

Comment: Yes! I just discover this, quite simple conversion! Thanks again.